# TypeError: Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Making app on ionic and getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined

Kindly check my code what mistake I done .Just make a simple image sharing App where I getting the error on social sharing plugin kindly check the code below and suggest me what should I do to correct that.

```
.controller('imageCtrl',function($scope,$cordovaSocialSharing,$http,$window) {
    $scope.myImages = [
        {id :'1',image:'1.jpg'},
        {id :'2',image:'2.jpg'},

    ];

    $scope.getImagePath = function(imageName) {
        return "img/" + imageName.image;
    }

    $scope.doit= function(index){
        console.log(index);

    }
    $scope.share = function(t, msg, img, link){
        if(t == 'w')
            window.plugins.socialsharing
                .shareViaWhatsApp(msg, img, link);
        else if(t == 'f')
            window.plugins.socialsharing
                .shareViaFacebook(msg, img, link);
        else if(t == 't')
            window.plugins.socialsharing
                .shareViaTwitter(msg, img, link);
        else if(t == 'sms')
            window.plugins.socialsharing
                .shareViaSMS(msg+' '+img+' '+link);
        else
        {
            var sub = 'Beautiful images inside ..';
            window.plugins.socialsharing
                .shareViaEmail(msg, sub, '');
        }
    }
});
```

App.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','app.controllers','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

HTML part

```
<ion-content ng-controller="imageCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="myImage in myImages" ng-click="doit($index)">
        {{myImage.id}}
        <img class ="col  item item-image thumbnail" ng-src="{{getImagePath(myImage)}}"/>
        <div class="card gallary item item-divider">
            <div class="item item-text-wrap row">
                <button ng-click="share('w', '', myImage.image, '');"
                        class="button button-light col col-20">
                    <i class="icon ion-social-whatsapp"></i>
                </button>
                <button ng-click="share('f', 'myMessage', myImage.image, '');"
                        class="button button-light col col-20">
                    <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i>
                </button>
                <button ng-click="share('t', 'myMessage', myImage.image, '');"
                        class="button button-light col col-20">
                    <i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Check the image [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try is like its [documented](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/) by using `$cordovaSocialSharing` service. PLease note that `shareViaEmail()` should be `canShareViaEmail()`. You may going to use `switch` instead of this `if - if else - if else - if else - else` pattern:

```
$scope.share = function(t, msg, img, link){
    switch (t) {
        case "w":
            $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp(msg, img, link);
            break;
        case "f":
            $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaFacebook(msg, img, link);
            break;
        case "t":
            $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaTwitter(msg, img, link);
            break;
        case "sms":
            $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaSMS(msg + ' ' + img + ' ' + link);
            break;

        default:
            $cordovaSocialSharing.canShareViaEmail(msg, 'Beautiful images inside ..', '');
            break;
    }
};
```

**Note**: This will only work on mobile devices and not in a desktop browser case.

Comment: Try: `console.log($cordovaSocialSharing);` is it undefined?

Comment: `window.plugins.socialsharing` isnt represented in my answer. So what error is comming up now?

Comment: console.log($cordovaSocialSharing); have object

Comment: This can't be true `window.plugins.socialsharing` is not used in this answer. Clear your browser cache.

Comment: @IndianThinking Are you testing it on browser or mobile device? I promise this will only work on mobile devices.

Comment: checking in browser

Comment: @IndianThinking Please build your app and try it on a mobile device. I added a note to my answer. The plugin itself it made for `PhoneGap Social Sharing plugin for Android, iOS and Windows Phone` -> means "no desktop browser support". Taken from the docu: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: its opening the whatsapp and other social apps but no msg  or image is not display

Comment: Please read the documentation carefully: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin there are a lot of limitations on sharing "msg", "images", etc.